# Idiomatic way to insert text from one application into another with GTK+ 3.0?

Tags: gtk, x11, vala, wayland

I'm working on an "emoji picker" (a.k.a. Unicode character palette). I've got the search and character history working but currently it just copies the character into the clipboard. Is there an idiomatic way to insert a selected character into the previously focused application from GTK+ 3.0?

For example, with `xdotool`, this is trivial to do from a shell: `xdotool type --delay 50 ""` will insert .

I'm currently working in Vala but am comfortable with C documentation. If I need to use X11- or Wayland-specific APIs, that's fine, but pointing me to documentation for both would be great.

Comment: ibus may be what your looking for, someone already implemented an ibus based emoji picker somewhere

Comment: https://github.com/mike-fabian/ibus-typing-booster